# Turn off Game Mode notifications for UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

We are an ISV. We distribute a UWP business app to businesses through the Microsoft Store. In  the last few days, each time our app starts, our users see messages from Microsoft telling them to turn on game mode. What can we do as developers to ensure potential users do not get these messages?

These messages have also started appearing when we run our app on our dev machines.

Our app has been in the Microsoft Store since June 2018. Our app targets Windows 10 1803. These messages have only appeared in the last few days.

Our app is not a game and these messages are inappropriate for our users and interfere with their productivity using our app. These messages may also impact our sales.

Our app is listed as a Business app in the Microsoft Store. We do not have access to users machines as they are independent businesses. What can we do as developers to ensure users do not get these messages?

Comment: Is the app on dev machine sideload or installed from the Microsoft Store? What the category did you choose when you submit the app in Dashboard Properties page?

Comment: As I said in my post @DasiyTianMSFT our app is listed in the Microsoft Store as a business app (Dashboard Properties page). We don't side-load. We get these messages after installing from the store as well as running from Visual Studio. The messages appear each time the app starts.